# CKRecord get value for key

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckrecord

I'm trying to get values for a user based on their username. I am able to get the correct user using:

```
class func getByUsername(username: String, callback: (records: [CKRecord]) -> ()){
    getSummary(NSPredicate(format: "Username == %@", username)){(records: [CKRecord]) -> Void in
        callback(records: records)
    }
}

class func getSummary(predicate: NSPredicate, callback: (records: [CKRecord]) -> ()){
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "UserInfo", predicate: predicate)
    let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["ID"]

    var records = [CKRecord]()
    queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = {record in records.append(record)}
    queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = {_ in callback(records: records)}

    CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.addOperation(queryOperation)
}
```

and I am then able to get the correct record by calling:

```
getByUsername("Username"){(records: [CKRecord]) -> Void in
  var record: CKRecord = records[0]
}
```

and I can also get the correct ID by using

```
var id: String = record.recordID.recordName
```

So I know for a fact that I am fetching the correct record, but, when I try to get values from the record, such as the user's email, `nil` is returned:

```
var email: String = record.objectForKey("Email") as String
```

I've also tried:

```
record.valueForKey("Email")
record.valueForKeyPath("Email")
```

When I print `record.allKeys()`, I get an empty array, `[]`, and when I print `record.allTokens()`, I get a return of `nil`

Am I not fetching a value from the record correctly, or do I have to query the database for every single value that I would like to get using the record ID? Based on what [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecord_class/index.html) says:

> A CKRecord object is a dictionary of key-value pairs that you use to fetch and save the data of your app.

I would assume that I do not have to query the database for every value that I would like to get, and that the values are automatically inserted into the `CKRecord` upon getting it from `iCloud`

Comment: have you tried printing out [`allKeys`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecord_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKRecord/allKeys) from your CKRecord object, to see what keys it does contain?

Comment: Try leaving out the line: 'queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["ID"]' there you limit the returning result to only the ID. Then you should have an ID in the allKeys. So maybe you don't have the field with the name ID?

Comment: @EdwinVermeer That does seem to be the error, thanks, what I don't understand is why `queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["ID"]` doesn't work, because there is a field with the name `ID`... Thanks again, though! Please answer the question, so I can make this the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you leave out the line:

```
queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["ID"]
```

the query will return all the fields.

That you did not receive the ID field is probably because its a system field which can be accessed using

```
var ID = record.recordID.recordName
```

Comment: Note that the query will only return fields with values, so fields with no value will not be returned.